# Why are the questions on Meta Stack Overflow so popular?

Tags: discussion

I often see the number of votes/answers/general interest in questions on Meta Stack Overflow to be much higher in number. There isn't much doubt that the questions here are a lot more interesting and prone to debate.

But shouldn't people spend time giving answers there rather than here?

I mean, that is what is more productive, right?

Comment: Well, each of the sites have their very own purpose.Are you going to compare apples with pears?

Comment: OP, what are you doing here‽ There are questions on StackOverflow which need answering!

Comment: _"I mean that is what is more productive right?"_ So discussing site policy and trying to hash out ways to make the site a better place (via discussing moderation, cleanup of dead or misused tags, and feature requests) is not productive?

Comment: @Trobbins:  +1 on the use of an interrobang.

Comment: Trying to ward off future problems isn't productive ([meta-tag:feature-request])?  Cleaning up past problems isn't productive ([meta-tag:burnination-request])?

Comment: I just find that a lot of questions are answered unsatisfactorily on SO. If a number of high-rep users let go of debates here, won't the Q/A database improve at a much higher rate?

Comment: It is advertised well, big yellow box in a prime position.  And everybody has an opinion, nice when you don't have to be accurate.

Comment: @KalpeshKrishna We're certainly not going to debate about every single question from the main site here. That would become way unproductive and unuseful!

Comment: A debate isn't needed on every question. But the full utilization of the community's knowledge is essential in my opinion.

Comment: @Kalpesh *full utilization of the community's knowledge is essential*. Indeed, but 2 remarks: 1. Not only are people required to answer the actual questions, you also need people to talk about how the site works/should work  2. 'full utilization' is overasking. Everybody here volunteers his time, and (so) is free to choose where

Comment: `I just find that a lot of questions are answered unsatisfactorily on SO` that's hardly because some people contribute on Meta (SO gets as many questions as there are on Meta in total *within 2 days!*), and it would hardly change if they stopped doing so.

Comment: The amount of questions asked on Meta in one day is only a very small fraction of the amount of questions asked on Main in one day. If you have less posts to view among the same number of users, you get more votes on individual posts. The fact that posts on Meta average more votes than on Main does not mean anything besides that there are less posts per person viewing them on Meta than on Main.

Answer (score 17):

I don't share your view that there is more interest for questions here than on the main site. What I do see is this:

- There are more 'subject experts' here on MSO than on SO for specific tags. The population on SO is mostly interested in their own tags while people here are broader since it concerns the entire site, which everyone knows.
- There are far fewer posts on MSO. Thus they got more attention per question than questions on the main site. Also the 'hot meta questions' box will draw even more attention.
- Concerning the votes: opinions draw more votes in general since people want to have their opinion reflected. A question on SO itself is mostly judged on the correctness and has less 'emotional' way of voting.

Comment: I think your first bullet point is pretty spot on for the noted behavior.

Answer (score 10):

I see two primary reasons:

1. The people that really *use* Stack Overflow, the people constantly on it (often with high rep counts) are the frequent visitors here, because they care about the site.
2. Which, combined with the fact that meta gets *far* fewer posts than SO (maybe 100 a day instead of thousands) means that each of those questions gets attention from many, if not all, of them whereas each main site question can only get attention from a few.

Thus, the view/vote counts tend to be much higher here.

Answer (score 4):

There are 10million+ questions on SO and only 15thousand+ on meta.SO.

There are about 400 bounties at any give time on SO. Meta.SO doesn't have bounties but does have the "Hot meta posts" which features about 4 questions at any one time from meta.SO on meta.SO and SO.

So as you can see, much easier for people to find one/two/three really popular meta.SO posts, since it's a much more narrow area. Whereas SO has hundreds of different areas and most people only frequent a few areas.

So meta.SO is the only bar in town, but SO has many work places.

Comment: Regarding the comparative number of questions should be noted that meta.so is much younger than the main site and is only 1 year and a bit old.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Sure, but that discounting works both ways: If you discount the time before the split, you also need to discount the posts from then.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reputation linked with votes on meta stack overflow. Upvoting or downvoting here has no effect whatsoever on what we can do in the sites, which makes the voices in our heads lot more calmer about up or down voting content.

that, and votes here are more of an expression of our consent (or disconsent) with the content that we see, not if said content is of high quality or greatly researched.